# It is advisable using libraries like @vitalets/google-translate-api or translate directly from react-native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am testing these "[translate](https://github.com/franciscop/translate)" and "[google-translate-api](https://github.com/vitalets/google-translate-api)" libraries, they are fantastic, I can translate to all google translate languages directly in react-native, but they can give me problems since it is unlimited and free.

I am building an application with a chat where people of different languages can chat and I am adding the option to translate the chats so that there can be a more fluid communication between people who speak different languages.

When reviewing the code of these libraries I realize that they call this URL: [https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=$%7Bfrom%7D&tl=$%7Bto%7D&dt=t&q=${](https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=$%7Bfrom%7D&tl=$%7Bto%7D&dt=t&q=$%7B) encodeURI(text)}`

This gives me the translated phrase as a result, in this way each user (client) can translate the chats directly from the application, but can calling that URL that is apparently free give me any problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about legality, not programming

Answer (score 0):

This is not a legal forum. Nor should you rely on legal forums even if it were the case. Your best course of action is to consult a lawyer that has experience with IP and licenses.

Keep in mind that in general each license has its own caveat. And having available source code does not equal free-to-use as I heard some claim or assume. It is an incorrect assumption and can lead to trouble. Second caveat of license is when using multiple third-parties. Some apparently "free-to-use" licenses (and I say "apparently" as some have some conditions, i.e. not for commercial use) might not be compatible with other apparently "free-to-use" licenses. Again, consult a lawyer on how to handle such scenarios.

This is as far as any "legal advice" can go on this forum. TLDR: talk to a layer.